# What is the correct interpretation of this question?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, visualization

This is from page $46$ of *Visual Complex Analysis* by Needham:

> [image]

This is my interpretation of the situation, which I think to be wrong:

[image]

I think my interpretation is wrong for the following reason: Take $L$ to be the vertical line passing through $(2, 0)$. Then $\phi = \dfrac {\pi}{2}$ and $d = 2$. Take $z = (2, 0)$. Then the point $e^{-i \frac {\pi}{2}}z$ lies on the horizontal axis, so its imaginary part is $0 \not = d$.

Another reason why I think it's wrong is that the expression $d$ is supposed to be equal to does not seem constant.

Comment: Arguing from the picture: Recall that the effect of multiplying the line by the exponential term is rotating the line by an angle of $\phi$ clockwise.  This will rotate the line to the line $y = -d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{-i\pi/2}z = -2i$, which is purely imaginary, and things work out nicely. Note that $z$ is not part of the exponent.

Comment: Oops! I know $z$ is not part of the exponent, I just imagined $\dfrac {\pi}{2}$ rotating a point by $180$ degrees rather than $90$. Well then I guess my interpretation is correct, and my intuition that the quantity $|Im[e^{-i \phi} z]$ depends on $z$ is wrong, right?